# What is the proper way to create a bean asynchronously using Weld SE (CDI)?

Tags: java, cdi, weld

I am using a Weld SE container in my JavaFX application (via AfterburnerFX actually). A component is initialized (when a dialog window is shown to the user) and it's fields are injected. However, creating one of its dependencies takes much time.

Is there an available facility to instantiate a bean **asynchronously** directly in Weld SE? If not, what's a common design pattern to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control instantiation programmatically, you can inject a `Provider` for your component instead:

```
//Instead of
@Inject MyComponent comp;

// do this:
@Inject Provider<MyComponent> compProvider;

// Usage in code at any given time:
MyComponent comp = compProvider.get();
```

Note that you will probably get to the alternative `Instance` instead of `Provider` at some time in the future (or a different answer) which is an extended interface implementing provider and some more useful functions.

Comment: What I want is to create a bean at startup asynchronously, so that I can later just inject an existing instance. Declaring `Instance` or `Provider` as I can see delays creating until `get` method is called.

Comment: @cassio-mazzochi-molin how does it refer to this question?

Comment: @Valya For asynchronous creation there is no direct way that I am aware of. With the method described in the answer, you can control the bean creation yourself and perform it in a different thread.